# laravel 5.4 joint table using distinct or Groupby

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm going to join 4 tables and use `distinct` but it's not working. how to slove this problem... or any other method please share
 me... thanking you. Below is my code

```
$subcategory = \DB::table('category')                            
            ->join('subcategory', 'subcategory.category_id', '=', 'category.id')
            ->join('product', 'product.subcategory_id', '=', 'subcategory.id')
            ->join('product_price', 'product_price.product_id', '=', 'product.id')
            ->where('product.delete', '!=',1)                      
            ->where('category.id', '=', @$categories_page[0]->id)                      
            ->where('product_price.seller_price', '!=',0.00)                      
            ->where('product_price.admin_approved', '!=',0)                      
            ->orderBy($column_name,$orderBy) 
            ->distinct('product.id')
             ->simplePaginate($show_limits);
dd($subcategory);
```

Comment: what was the error ?

Comment: When you apply DISTINCT you can't order by a column which is not included in the Select-list.

Comment: No error but i have got dublicate values (product_id) ..thanking you..

Comment: please any example..thanking you..

Comment: Can you show some result rows with duplicates?

Comment: sorry for delay http://prntscr.com/ic9ars ...see product_id

Comment: I don't know about laravel, but it looks like you got lots of columns in your result/Select list. DISTINCT always applies to all columns in Select, you probably got different data in other columns.

Comment: please post your SQL equivalent to see if there is error `$subcategory->toSql()`